# Application load in angular 2, very slow

Tags: angular

I am making an application in Angular 2, the problem I encounter is the loading speed, the inspector shows me that it performs 197 requests.
The url is as follows:
http://www.globalmedicalhistory.com/app.html

My project starts with the following:
https://github.com/moizKachwala/Angular2-express-mongoose-gulp-node-typescript

Which also has the same problem.
Anyone have a solution? thank you very much!!

Comment: How did you build the application?  I'm not quite sure how to interpret the many 304 responses on load - it seems there's a slew of redundant requests.

Comment: You can download my starter app: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-starter-app.  It demonstrates AOT tree shaking, which reduces the number of requests to 3: app bundle, vendor bundle, styles bundle. Each is compressed and minified as well.

Comment: Also, are you lazy-loading?  If not, that would be a primary culprit.

Comment: This is not even an Angular problem, just one of not packaging your app correctly. Accept Vineet's answer and do as he says. Webpack+AOT will give you a handful of minified, tree-shaken files and that is what you need to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I am not a big fan of making single repo for backend and frontend. That said, I cannot convince many people from doing so, I am pretty sure I cannot convince you too.

Now please go to - https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter and pull the frontend project. for writing your server code you can build your own script in node js using the same code of gulp serve tasks. Say you wrote your server starting code in start-server.js

And in package.json you can wrtie command "node start-server.js" inside "start" script.

I strongly suggest to develop angular2 project in separate environment than your express server. It will make your life very easy.

Also compile your app with angular2's aot compiler and then serve your build folder with express server.